# WiFi Problems , including priority and not being able to connect to certain networks

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

So I am trying to setup my RPI4 wpa_supplicant.conf file with priority for my different networks , but the file just keeps reverting back to what it was before i edited it , and it also disable the other networks except the one it connected to the last time.

Also I can't get it to connect to my iPhone's hotspot, it tries indefinitely to connect to my iPhone.

any workarounds for this? this is absolute necessity as i don't have an keyboards to connect to my RPI so without the RPI being connected to a network I can't use it.

P.S.: I have read other questions but none of their answers worked for me.

Comment: The revert infers the card is going faulty.  Try `sudo touch /boot/readonly` to create a file in /boot, reboot the pi and then check if the file exists in /boot.  If not your card is now in read only mode and possibly about to fail.

Comment: @andrew the card is working fine, i edit other configuration , download files just fine, in addition to this i have had a card go read only , the pi won't even boot if the card goes read only , at least in my case , i will try this anyway but i don't this would be the case